# Looking for a book from the 70s probably about space war and robots

Tags: story-identification, robots, dystopia, cyborg

Looking for a book from my childhood. It would be from the 70s, probably '77 or later, and my recollection is it was a dystopian book about a war between humans and androids or cyborgs.

It was an oversized paperback book with black and white illustrations.  I think it also had some kind of "code wheel" built into the cover to solve codes in the book.

I do not remember a title or an author.

The book was actually a puzzle book and wove the story and the puzzles together.  I don't know if you had to complete the puzzles to follow the story.  I remember one puzzle involved plotting points in 3D, and I could never figure out how they derived their answer.

It was probably a YA book, and since I was only 8 or 9 it was probably over my head which is why it didn't click with me at the time.

But now I've been googling furiously trying to find it but coming up empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.  The name of the book is *Star Games* by Jim Razzi, Rick Brightfield and Jack Looney.

Interestingly, Jim Razzi's name kept popping up in all my googling because he has a large back catalog of puzzle books with tie ins to movies like Star Wars and Star Trek.  His *Star Trek Puzzle Compendium* would frequently appear at the top of the list.

However *Star Games* is not tied to any property.  It's a story that stands alone.  The idea seems to be a series of games to train you for fighting in some galactic war.

To finally find the book I had to go to the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/) and go through the book list for '77 and '78 and click on anything that might sound right.  I finally had that ``Eureka!'' moment.

You can actually [see the book at BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/45337/star-games-space-adventure) of all places.  Someone was more obsessed with it than me and tracked the book down and took photos of I think all the pages.